# In python, how to use __str__ to return elements in a list, line by line

Tags: python

I have a class `Numberlist` which takes a list of numbers.

```
class Numberlist:
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number
    def __str__(self):
        for i in self.number:
            print(i)
        return '{}'.format('')
```

I want to display the list of numbers in the following format when printing a object.

```
x = Numberlist([1,2,3,4,5,6])
print(x)
print("done printing")
```

```
1 
2 
3
4
5
6

done printing
```

My attempt is not correct because there is an empty line at the end of the output. I am stuck because `__str__` requires you to return string type element.

Comment: `return '\n'.join(map(str, self.number))`

Comment: You shouldn't be `print`ing in `__str__`; it should strictly return. Just `join` the numbers with a newline.

Answer (score 3):

## What you're seeing

You're seeing an extra newline because you're printing every element in the list in your `__str__` function then printing the value returned from `__str__`: namely, `""`. Unless you designate `end` in `print`, it defaults to a newline, so you're effectively printing `"\n"`.

## What you (probably) want to do

You probably want to print just the stringified representation of your class. If that's each element newline-delimited, I'd define `__str__` in the following way:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join(map(str, self.number))
```

This will put a newline between the string representation of each element in `self.number` and return that single string.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I was reading a similar post before and trying to use join(), but I got an error. No I understand it is because I am dealing with a list of integers instead of strings.